# Flip Fluids Baking Error

Tags: add-on

I compiled the flip fluids addon from the source code on github and followed the tutorial, but when I bake it gives me this error, i used the mingw compiler and tried clearing the user preferences, but the error persist, what can I do?

[image]

Comment: You seem to have a 32 bit version of one and a 64 bit version of the other. find out which Blender is and recompile flip the same. how depends on your os

Comment: I installed python yesterday from the windows terminal, maybe I installed it in 32 bit, but I think blender is in 64 bit

Comment: Ok, I checked and they are both 64 bits